# Select border color

Tags: html, css, html-select, opera

I don't seem to be able to get rid of the border (outline, box-shadow?) against the `select` element in `Opera` browser.

None of the below rules are removing the border:

```css
select {
  /*border: 0;*/
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-image: none;
  outline-offset: -2px;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">Most Popular</option>
  <option value="1">A-Z</option>
  <option value="2">Z-A</option>
  <option value="3">Lowest price</option>
  <option value="4">Highest price</option>
</select>
```

`Opera` version is 46.0.2597.57 (PGO).

The above code is working perfectly in other browsers tested - Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Edge.

Any hint would be helpful.

**EDIT** I am using Windows 10 64-bit, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I sincerely wish that one day "_Don't use Opera_" will be a valid answer... ;)

Comment: Maybe you'll have to use something like `border: 1px solid white` to overlap Opera's border. Or just apply custom styles to your `select` via removing standard appearance using `-webkit-appearance: none`.

Comment: @Frits agree with you, but can't argue the customer :) @Vadim Ovchinnikov I still need to show the arrow so `-webkit-appearance: none` is not a solution, also as border one. However, `border: 1px solid transparent` would be a good one, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I have seen some people mention that they had to do `select, select:focus, select:active { outline: 0 !important; }` to get this to work. I haven't installed Opera on this machine yet so am unable to test it for you though. Maybe see if it works?

Comment: @Frits just tested, doesn't help

Comment: Could you post a screenie? I've just installed Opera (although it's on my Mac) and [there was no border showing on the select field?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyVjq.png)

Comment: [Don't use outline:none; if you aren't going to redefine a focus style](http://www.outlinenone.com/)

Comment: @Ihazkode whilst I agree with the link you posted, I do feel that you should clarify your statement to fit the content of the link provided. i.e.: _Don't use outline:none; if you aren't going to redefine a focus style._ which makes much more sense :)

Comment: @Frits see the edit. @I haz kode usually I am not removing default outline at all, the example is just to show that nothing helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get rid of the border with `-webkit-appearance: none;`, but this removes the caret too, so you might have to add this again manually. I could not manage to find a better answer to this, since opera is really stubborn with this border. *(Updated solution with caret below)*

```css
select {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-image: none;
  outline-offset: -2px;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="1">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">Most Popular</option> 
  <option value="1">A-Z</option>
  <option value="2">Z-A</option>
  <option value="3">Lowest price</option>
  <option value="4">Highest price</option>
</select>
```

**Updated solution:** This is more like a workaround, than a solution, but this has a working "fake" caret, and looks like a borderless dropdown, even in Opera.

```css
select {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-image: none;
  outline-offset: -2px;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100% ;
  position: absolute;
}

.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.select-wrapper:after {
  content: "\25BE";
  float: right;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper" id="label-for-1">
  <select class="form-control" id="1">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Most Popular</option>
    <option value="1">A-Z</option>
    <option value="2">Z-A</option>
    <option value="3">Lowest price</option>
    <option value="4">Highest price</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like `border: 1px solid white` to overlap Opera's border if you have solid background behind your `select`.

Or you can apply custom styles for webkit browsers to your `select` via CSS hacks targeting specific browser, removing standard appearance using `-webkit-appearance: none` and applying SVG `background-image` for standard arrow. This way standard appearance for IE and Firefox will be intact.

```css
select {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Select only webkit browsers */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  select {
    /* remove arrow */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    /* add some padding for image */
    padding-right: 15px; 
    /* apply SVG with arrow */
    /* change width value to move arrow to the left */
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15"><path d="M 8,5.5 11,9.5 14,5.5 z"></path></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">Most Popular</option>
  <option value="1">A-Z</option>
  <option value="2">Z-A</option>
  <option value="3">Lowest price</option>
  <option value="4">Highest price</option>
</select>
```